# Adding dynamically rows to Bootstrap Gridlayout with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Today I facing a new problem. My resource has a few items in a format(json) and I will present the data within a Bootstrap Gridlayout.

```
       <div class="row">
            <div class="Box">
                <div ng-repeat="sub in subscribed | filter:searchFilter" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                            <h6 class="text-muted">{{ sub.genre }} / {{ sub.seasons }} Season(s)</h6>
                            <p></p>
                            <p><a href="#sub/{{ sub.id }}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">More...</a>           </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>
     </div>
```

When I add more than 3 items in my contentbox (width:800px, height:600px), bootstrap overwrites the previous items. 
How can I add a new row with AngularJs or is there a little Bootstrap-trick?

**Edit**

Here is a code snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/LaPpd/
I get always a overlay from one row.

**Edit 2**

Sorry guys, I had a div with absolute position.

Comment: you shouldn't have an explicit height set. Also I would recommend using Angular-Grid (ngGrid) instead of bootstrap Gridlayout for this type of data.

Comment: Dump Question: How do I add custom items like a bootstrap "thumbnail"?